# QT5 Initializer but not implemented

Tags: c++, qt

Hello I read all other questions but was not cleared in my mind, please, sorry if mean duplicated question but I have no option to solve this.

I am using QT 5 on a Ubuntu Machine with G++/GCC.
So, I am compiling and I get this error:

```
src/rolebit.cpp:279:26: error: variable 'startWindowImpl mainWin' has initializer but incomplete type
  startWindowImpl mainWin(myConfig,myLog);
```

So, from rolebit.cpp file I have this implementation:

```
#ifdef QML_CLIENT
//START THE QML SWITCH HERE
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <QApplication>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include "configfile.h"
#include "qmlwrapper.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    boost::shared_ptr<ConfigFile> myConfig;
    myConfig.reset(new ConfigFile(argv[0], false));

    QmlWrapper myQml(myConfig);
    return app.exec();
}
```

**BUT after this I have this lines:**

```
#else
// START OF OLD QT-WIDGETS GUI SECTION


#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <qapplication.h>

#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
#include <QtWidgets>
#endif
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#if QT_VERSION < 0x050000
#include <QMacStyle>
#endif
#endif

#include <curl/curl.h>

#include "session.h"
#include "startwindowimpl.h"
#include "configfile.h"
#include "log.h"
#include "startsplash.h"
#include "game_defs.h"
#include <net/socket_startup.h>
#include <third_party/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>

#define ENABLE_LEAK_CHECK() \
{ \
    int tmpFlag = _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG); \
    tmpFlag |= _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF; \
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(tmpFlag); \
    }
#endif
#endif

#ifndef ENABLE_LEAK_CHECK
#define ENABLE_LEAK_CHECK()
#endif
```

And the line that I have the problem is:

```
startWindowImpl mainWin(myConfig,myLog);
```

So, what I need to do to work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `startWindowImpl` class is fully declared in "startwindowimpl.h" but you don't have line `#include "startwindowimpl.h"` in first part of your code. So when `QML_CLIENT` is `#define`d this header is not included, which makes full declaration of class `startWindowImpl` unknown.

Comment: Hello mvidelgauz, thank you for your reply!
I look into the code and I see that in second line (for QT5) I have startwindowimpl.h yet. But I include in first lines of include and I get the same error.

EDIT

Thank you, I find the problem based on your tip. My "startwindowimpl.h" was with 0kb file, I look into the file and has 0 lines. I backup the code and now are working. Thank you

Comment: than probably your posted code is not enough to guess about your problem. please add content of your .h files